# Select Ids which have both NULL and Value(NOT NULL) in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to select IDs, which have both `NULL` and `NOT NULL` value in different column of same table?

Table:
    `Col1   |   Col2`
   `abc    |   NULL`
    `abc    |   123`
   `bcd    |   456`

Result
    `Col1   |   Col2`
   `abc    |   NULL`
    `abc    |   123`

Comment: With that data, what's the expected result? (Perhaps you should to add some more rows sample data, to make things even clearer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select Col1 
from mytable
group by Col1
having count(case when col1 is null then 1 end) > 0 and
       count(case when col1 is not null then 1 end) > 0
```

This will select `Col1` values being related to both `NULL` and `NOT NULL` `col2` values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking.

Do you want rows where the 2 fields in the same rows have the same value, whether NULL or not?

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT col1 INTERSECT SELECT col2)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65ed2/1) example

Or otherwise if you want "where values exists in any row in another column"

```
SELECT col1 FROM SomeTable
INTERSECT
SELECT col2 FROM SomeTable
```

[SQLFiddle take 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65ed2/3)

Both of these work because INTERSECT compares internally using "IS" logic instead of "=". 
See [Paul White (SQLKiwi)](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx) for more

Answer (score 0):

You can use isnulll() function.

like this

```
where isnull(col1,0)=isnull(col2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

see,if you use identity column or use row_number in query then it is very easy

```
Declare @table table (id int identity(1,1)
,Col1 varchar(50),Col2 varchar(50))
insert into @table
values
('abc', NULL )
,('abc', '123')
,('bcd' ,'456')


select a.col1,a.col2
from @table A
inner join @table b on a.col1=b.col1 and a.id<>b.id
```

OR

```
;with CTE as
(
select a.col1,a.col2,row_number()over(order by col1) rn
from @table A
)
select a.col1,a.col2
from CTE A
inner join CTE b on a.col1=b.col1 and a.rn<>b.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @table table
(
  col1 nvarchar(10),
  col2 integer
 )
 insert into @table
 (col1)
 values
 ('abc')

insert into @table
 (col1,col2)
 values
  ('abc',123),
 ('bcd',456)

select col1,col2 from @table where col1 in 
 (
 select col1 
 from
 (
 select col1,
    sum(case when col2 is null then 1 else 0 end) as nulls,
    sum(case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) as notnulls
  from @table
  group by col1
 )  s
 where  nulls <> 0 and notnulls <> 0
)